# Determining derivatives of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

For what function $f$ and number $a$ is the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/4} \frac {\tan x - 1}{4x-\pi}$$

the value of $f’(a)$?

All I’m asking is how I would begin solving this problem.

Comment: denominator is $4(x-\pi/4)$ and $1=tan({\pi}/4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you would BEGIN solving this problem is to bear in mind that
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.
$$
In the denominator you have $4x-\pi,$ so you can write
$$
\frac{\quad\cdots\cdots\quad}{4x-\pi} \quad = \quad  \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac{\quad\cdots\cdots\quad}{x - \frac \pi 4}.
$$
That should suggest what number $a$ is.

Comment: But that limit is still in “0/0” form. How do I simplify it so that {\pi}/{4} becomes substitutable?

Comment: er484483 : The way you phrased the question, it was about how to find $a$ and $f,$ not about how to find the limit. Since you have $$ \frac{\frac 1 4 \tan x - \frac 1 4}{x-\frac\pi 4}, $$ and $\dfrac 1 4 \tan \dfrac\pi 4 = \dfrac 1 4,$ this is $\dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$ when $a= \pi/4$ and $f(x) = (1/4)\tan x.$ Therefore the limit is $f'(\pi/4) = \dfrac 1 4 \sec^2\dfrac \pi 4 = \dfrac 1 2.$ But making $\pi/4$ "substitutable" is not how this particular kind of limit would usually be evaluated. Usually it would be found by doing something like this:$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: Find $\dfrac d {dx} \tan x$ by writing it as $\dfrac d{dx}\, \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and then apply the quotient rule, and finally substitute $\pi/4$ into the resulting function, and of course multiply by $1/4.$ This leaves the question of how to find $\dfrac d {dx} \sin x$ and $\dfrac d {dx} \cos x.$ For the former, you have $$ \begin{align} \frac d {dx} \sin x & = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin x} h \\ \\ & = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin x\cos h + \cos x \sin h - \sin x} h & & (\text{a trigonomertric identity}) \\  \\ & = \cdots \text{to be continued below}  \end{align}$$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & = (\sin x) \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos h - 1} h + (\cos x) \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin h} h \\  \\ & = \cos x \end{align} $$ where the last to limits are found by arguments involving squeezing rather than by making $0$ "substitutable". $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

In general

$$
f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \tag{1}
$$

With this in mind, rewrite your limit as

$$
\frac{1}{4}\lim_{x\to \pi/4} \frac{\tan x - \tan(\pi/4)}{x - \pi/4} \tag{2}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: What I was confused about was evaluating the limit itself (i.e. simplifying it from the current “0/0” form).

Comment: I'm inclined to think one should usually follow the notatin of the question, i.e. calling it "$a$" instead of "$x_0$" would be better.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right, I changed it

Comment: @user484483 : The way you wrote the question, how to find the limit is not what the question is about.

Comment: Right, but in order to solve the problem you have to evaluate the given limit first.

Answer (score 0):

> HINT, for the limit use:
>
> $$\tan\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}\tag1$$

---

So, we get:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\tan\left(x\right)-1}{4x-\pi}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}-1}{4x-\pi}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\pi-4x\right)}=$$
$$\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{1}{\cos\left(x\right)}\right\}\cdot\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)}{\pi-4x}\right\}=$$
$$\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{1}{\cos\left(x\right)}\right\}\cdot\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\pi-4x\right)}\right\}=$$
$$\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{1}{\cos\left(x\right)}\right\}\cdot\left\{\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\space\frac{\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)}{4}\right\}\tag2$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Read the comment under the answer of #caverac